# Three.js - Open PerspectiveCamera showing bounding Sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a Scene which loads one `.obj` file.

Using the `PerspectiveCamera` I wan't to start the scene with the object fully visible in the camera.

- FOV is fixed in 60
- Objects have variable size
- `TrackballControls` is used to control the camera

I tried [this solution](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6784#issuecomment-315968779) but didn't work.

The code:

```
FOV = 60

scene = new THREE.Scene()
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( FOV, 500 / 350, 0.1, 10000 )
scene.add( camera )

objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.load('/airboat.obj', function (object) {
  scene.add( object )

  var boundingBox = new THREE.Box3();
  boundingBox.setFromObject( object );
  var sphere = boundingBox.getBoundingSphere()

  // don't work
  var center = boundingBox.getCenter();
  var size = boundingBox.getSize();
  var maxDim = Math.max( size.x, size.y, size.z );
  var cameraZ = maxDim / 2 / Math.tan(Math.PI * FOV / 360);
  camera.lookAt(center)
  camera.position.set( center.x, center.y, cameraZ );
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
})
```

**EDIT**

I created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rodrigora/db7c5r93/7/) (scroll down the JS code) and @Brakebein solution works most of the times, but sometimes the bounding box edges are not visible

Comment: Add a wireframe box to the scene, where the bounding box is. If it still does not help to find the error, please give us more detail (or a screenshot), not just that "didn't work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to call `camera.lookAt(center)` after you set the camera's position:

```
camera.position.set( center.x, center.y, cameraZ );
camera.lookAt(center);
```

Or you could try the approach using the BoundingSphere as I use it in my project to fit objects into the view: (I'm using `OrbitControls`, but it should work the same with `TrackballControls`)

```
var sphere = boundingBox.getBoundingSphere();

// compute new distance between camera and center of object/sphere
var h = sphere.radius / Math.tan( camera.fov / 2 * THREE.Math.DEG2RAD );

// get direction of camera (when using Orbit or TrackballControls, the camera is
// always pointing  to the control's target, so I'm using this)
var dir = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(camera.position, controls.target);

// compute new camera position
var newPos = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(sphere.center, dir.setLength(h));

// copy values
camera.position.copy(newPos);
controls.target.copy(sphere.center);

camera.lookAt(controls.target); // -> you don't need to call this as this is already part of controls.update() routine
```

*Hint:* Make sure that camera and controls are not at the same position. Otherwise, it won't work to compute the direction.

**EDIT:** Ok, I got the hint from @Rabbid76's diagrams: My solution is basically accordant to the first one. In certain situations, parts of the object or bounding box will be outside of the viewing frustum. So the method shown in the second diagram is better. To do so, we just need to change `tan` to `sin`:

```
var h = sphere.radius / Math.sin( camera.fov / 2 * THREE.Math.DEG2RAD );
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks. But sometimes the scene opens with the `boundingBox` edges out of the view. Check the JsFiddle if you like

Comment: I edited my answer. Basically, you need to change `Math.tan` to `Math.sin`.

Answer (score 3):

The new camera target is the center of the sphere and the new camera position is shifted along the opposite direction of the current line of sight by the calculated distance:

The line of sight is the vector from the `camera.position` to the `controls.target`

```
var current_los = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(controls.target, camera.position);
```

The new target an positon are calcualted as follows:

```
var new_pos     = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(center, current_los.setLength(-cameraZ));
var new_target  = center;
```

Further the `position` of the camera has to be set before `look At` is called, because the function depends on the position and the `controls` have to be updated:

```
var boundingBox = new THREE.Box3();
boundingBox.setFromObject( group );

var center = boundingBox.getCenter();
var size   = boundingBox.getSize();

var distance = Math.max( size.x, size.y, size.z );
//var distance = boundingBox.getBoundingSphere().radius * 2;

//var cameraZ = distance / 2 / Math.tan(Math.PI * FOV / 360);
var cameraZ = distance / 2 / Math.sin(Math.PI * FOV / 360);

var current_los = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(controls.target, camera.position);
var new_pos     = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(center, current_los.setLength(-cameraZ));
var new_target  = center; 

// copy values
camera.position.copy(new_pos);
camera.lookAt(center);

controls.target.copy(center);
controls.update();
```

You will gain a slightly larger image section, if you use the diameter of the sphere which wraps the bounding box, instead of the maximum angle length of the box:

```
var distance = boundingBox.getBoundingSphere().radius * 2;
```

---

But note, this still may not do what you want. See the image:

[image: FOV sphere]

Probabl you want to do this:

[image: FOV sphere 2]

So you have to use the sine instead of the tangent:

```
sin(FOV/2) == (maxDim/2) / cameraZ;
```

```
var cameraZ = maxDim / 2 / Math.sin(Math.PI * FOV / 360);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer and images but didn't work https://jsfiddle.net/rodrigora/db7c5r93/8/

Comment: thanks for reviewing. Actually, I'm simulating my example above. The `THREE.OBJLoader()` class generates an `THREE.Group` object when it loads the `.obj` file. So in the jsfiddle I'm using the variable `group`. I believe the result is the same.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I copied the wrong link in my comment above: Your code is in this version: https://jsfiddle.net/rodrigora/db7c5r93/17/ your code starts at line 686

Comment: @Rodrigo I changed the answer. But maybe this is still not enough, because you want to take in account the different dimension on the x y and z axis of the bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

With loading the .obj and then setting the camera to be the 'center' of the .obj, you're telling the camera to move to the exact center of the obj you've loaded, rather than loading it in the view.

```
var center = boundingBox.getCenter(); //This gets the exact center of the box
```

What you will want to do is get the width and depth of the object you're loading and subtract that from the camer center position.

e.g.

```
camera.position.set( center.x - size.x, center.y - size.y, cameraZ - size.z );
```

The above snippet (untested), will move the camera position back the entire size of the object you're loading which should bring it into view. You could also subtract another 'buffer' that will allow you to see it more rather than being at the total edge bounds.

Hope this helps