# Three.js orbit control rotate and focus object

Tags: three.js, orbit.js

I am using Threejs and oribt control.

I want a feature, if I give the object name. orbit control should rotate and focus ( make visible in center of screen ).

Could some one help me on this?

Thanks,
Sabari.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: To place the camera, so that the object will fit to the viewport, you may have a look at those answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985714/three-js-open-perspectivecamera-showing-bounding-sphere